# Get conditional formatting to analyze rows separately

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have a calendar and I am trying to fill the background of the cells based on dates on another sheet.

I have gotten it to work by entering the dates in a columns, naming the range (lets says "Dates" for this example) by adding a rule to conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C8,Dates,1,FALSE)=C8
```

Using that formula in multiple rules got me this result:
[image]

From data on another page with dates entered into multiple columns and the ranges named for each separate color

But on my current project I have to fill in lots of dates in a row, like usually two weeks at a time. So I'm trying to add a rule to conditional formatting that will fill in the cells based on a start date and end date and ended up adding the following formula:

```
=AND(C8>=Start,C8<=End,WEEKDAY(C8,2)<6)
```

The problem I am running into is excel is evaluating all the entires in the Start and End columns and I'm hoping I can set it up for it evaluates each row separately. So for example I have a row with the dates 3/7/14 and 4/26/14 and the next row has 4/1/14 and 6/1/14. I would like the all dates to be formatted, (3/7/14-4/26/14 AND 4/1/14-6/1/14) but I'm only getting formatting for the dates that are in both entries (4/1/14-4/26/14).

So when I entered a formula that only looked at 3/7/14 and 4/26/14 I got this (which is what I am hoping I can do with all entires):
[image]

But when I name the first column range to be start and the next to end and enter it into the formula, only 4/1/14 to 4/25/14 are formatted (wanted to include another link to a pic with the result, but can only include two links in this post, sorry).

Any ideas on a different formula that will get me the result I am looking for? Or should I write a Macro instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to my own question and decided to share what I found out in case anyone else is trying something like this.

So to get my calendar to fill in correctly, I found this formula to use in conditional formatting.

=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Start<=C8)*(End>=C8)),1,0)

Honestly don't really understand why it worked, but needed to finish up this project so not worried about that right now.

I've included some pics for anyone who didn't understand what I was trying to do. Using in a Powerpoint so use these pages to create slides to demonstrate when our client was on medication due to an accident.

Actually can't post a pic so here is a link to the image if you want to see what I created.

http://s1.postimg.org/cmmsslsm7/Screen_Shot_2015_02_23_at_5_36_34_PM.png